# Why doesn't my Regular Expression for an empty string work?

Tags: regex, flash, actionscript-3

I've tested this on Regexr and it works, but it doesn't seem to work in AS3:

```
var emptyResult:* = new RegExp("^\s*$", "gi").exec(myField.text);
```

or

```
var emptyResult:* = /^\s*$/gi.exec(myField.text);
```

No matter whether I have text in the field or not, whitespace or non-whitespace, emptyResult is always null. I've tried with and without the g and i tags, but nothing seems to work.

Anyone know why this might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need the 'i' flag - it stands for 'ignore case', which is only applicable to letters of Latin alphabet - you aren't using them.
2. In the first example, you need to escape the backslash, otherwise it's treated as if it was meant to escape the following letter 's'.
3. You don't need the 'g' flag either, since you are trying to test the entire string (in your case the line and the string are the same thing, `\s` will first encounter the end of the line, before `$` can).
4. When using your second regexp, however, with the 'i' flag removed, it gives me the results I'd expect, i.e. if the entire text of the tested string consists of white space, tabulation, carriage return or line feed, then that entire string is returned.

For instance:

```
trace(/^\s*$/.exec(" \t\r\n")[0].length); // 4
```

Comment: Thanks. It turned out to be a combination of your point #2 and the fact I was doing the check the wrong way round (`emptyResult == null` instead of `emptyResult != null`). Ooops!